Dynamics CRM Plugin: Calling Web API with certificate in sandbox mode
trying to call an web API using client certificate in a plugin (D365 online) but i have this error "Permission request type 'System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, " (in this line  X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);)
when i load the certificate and block me to get a response from the API also i tried to call this api from a console application and got a response this my code
PS: my api use two authentification a certifcate and a basic user : if someone worked in this or have a solution please share it thanks
function callapi ()
try
{

  byte[] certificateBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secretvalue);
  // Load the certificate from the byte array
  X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);

  // Create an instance of HttpClientHandler
  HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
  handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

  using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
  {
  
    // Set the Basic Authentication header
    var username = "user";
    var password = "password";
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));

    // Convert the request body to JSON
    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputWS);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    // Make the API POST request
    HttpResponseMessage response1 = httpClient.PostAsync("webapilink", httpContent).Result;
    tracingService.Trace("response1", response1);
    if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode){
      tracingService.Trace("successs", response1.StatusCode + response1.ReasonPhrase);

    }
    else {
      tracingService.Trace("failed", response1.StatusCode + response1.ReasonPhrase);

    }
    string responseContent = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    OutputWS responseRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputWS>(responseContent);
    tracingService.Trace("responseRequest", responseRequest);


    tracingService.Trace("output function call", responseRequest);


    // Return the response content
    return responseRequest;

  }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw;
}


This error is probably related to plugins being executed in Sandbox isolation mode and the System.Security.Permissions namespace being historically problematic with partial-trust environments. The fact that your code works from a Console Application is a strong indication of this.
Unfortunately, there's not much you can do without changing the API authentication or building a proxy for it.
Please refer to Microsoft's recommendations for plugins accessing external web services.

thank you for your answer Federico, i have 2 questions is there other solution to consume the api ? also how to build a proxy for it ?

It's basically building a web application that acts as an intermediary between your plugin and the API. As you have full control of this proxy API, you can implement a sandbox-compatible authentication method and then use the other API with no issues. The downside is that you'd need to host this new API and there's an associated cost to it. Of course, you can also use something like Azure API Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/.

If you've got CRM Online, then the normal solution is to offload the processing to an environment that you have more control over. The most common option is to offload the processing to Azure, using the Azure Service Bus or Azure Event Hub .
Power automate, data flow, azure functions, azure event hub can be used

The error you are encountering, Permission request type 'System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission', suggests that the Dynamics 365 (D365) sandbox environment imposes restrictions on certain operations, particularly those involving cryptographic functions and accessing key containers.
you can using Azuer Function .
